# What is the correct place for driver sources?

Tags: directory-structure, fhs

I have some sources I want to compile using `make`. The sources will be compiled into a driver I'm going to use. What is the correct place for such files? /usr/share? /opt? /usr/local/...?

Edit: the driver is going to be a kernel driver, and I'll be using dkms for the installation. The distro I'll be using is Ubuntu, but I'll might also use it for other distros in the future

Comment: You should precise your OS (Linux ?), the type of driver (kernel module, CUPS driver, X11 driver, other…). Depending of the answer, we could give you a complete and accurate answer. Ideally you could point us the site which proposes the driver (you shouldn’t try to install things manually). In some cases, the installation is automated with a documented instruction. On Linux, you could have a directory per kernel version like `/lib/modules/4.14.79-xxxx-std-ipv6-6`

Comment: Also, for sources (not the compiled driver), `/usr/src` is a casual place, but is not mandatory.

Comment: You'd develop the package in your home directory, then when it is installed, DKMS will unpack it to `/usr/src`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really up to you but normally sources are stored in `/usr/src` as mentioned in the comments. Since system-wide installed applications could install their sources in this directory as well, to avoid possible conflicts, you could use `/usr/local/src` instead but again in the end no one stops you from storing sources **anywhere you want** as long as you remember where they are and there are no conflicts. You may as well create `/src` - easy to find, easy to `cd` to.